# Angular force page to execute directive added html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive that adds `spellcheck` attributes to 2 `div`'s like so:

```
(function(){  

  'use strict';

  app.directive('spellchecker', spellchecker);
  spellchecker.$inject = ['$timeout', '$compile'];

  function spellchecker($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          attrs.$set('contenteditable', true);
          attrs.$set('spellcheck', true);
          $compile(element)(scope); //<- this does not seem to do the trick for me.
        }
      }
    };
  };
})();
```

Haml

```
.title(spellchecker="{{!!preview}}") {{thing.title}}
```

`spellchecker="{{!!preview}}")` resolves to true.

I have also tried to achieve the same without a directive by wrapping the html with a `div` like so:

```
%div{'spellcheck':'true', 'contenteditable':'true'}
  .title {{thing.title}}
```

I want the directive to force the spellcheck on the page divs, however at the moment the spellcheck only works when clicking in any of the two `div`'s where the spellcheck attribute was added.
Do I have to compile the `div`'s html?

Comment: Yep, compile 'em.

Comment: Don't forget aboul priority and terminal. Set spellchecker terminal: true and priority higher than other directives on this divs

Comment: And btw, just `link` is a shorthand to `link: post`, so you can use just `link` and compile in the bottom of the `link`

Answer (score 0):

Shortly speaking, the answer is yes, you need to compile your added attributes or they will remain plain HTML with no use.

You can do this by simply adding $compile to your dependencies and use it:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('contenteditable', true);
      attrs.$set('spellcheck', true);
      $compile(element)(scope);  //element will contain added directives
  }
```

Comment: Yeah I kinda thought of that but is not executing the spell check on page load, it gets executed when clicking on divs.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code? i guess your issue could be solved by adding spellcheck=true to your divs

Comment: added html to question.

Comment: try to use in your html ng-attr-spellcheck="preview || undefined"